# CSS Background Image Distorted on Mobile

Tags: css

I'm trying to display a background image with the following CSS code in the header.

```
body {
        background-image: url("./image.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
       }
```

It works perfectly on desktop, even when I resize the browser window but when I try to access it on mobile, the image gets distorted and stretched to no more than a few pixels at the top of the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size: 100vw 100vh`

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://www.highreshdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Large-Format-HD-Wallpaper.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: This will now cut off the image whenever I resize the browser window on desktop as opposed to resizing the image too. Also, this still doesn't fill the entire mobile browser window

Comment: Oh, so you want the image to stretch in both directions? Try using 100vw 100vh instead of 100% 100%.